# Return the row in data frame containing a 'x' element in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In this code, I want to return the row of a data frame containing a certain element that is requested by the user. This is my code but it is not working. I would really appreciate your help.

**CODE**

```
x=data.frame(color=c('pink','blue','yellow','pink'),number=c(3,2,9,7),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

print(x)

input=readline('input an element: ')

n=nrow(x)

for(i in 1:n){
  if(input%in%x){
    print(x[i,])
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry guys the format of my code is weird. I am new to StackOverflow and messes up while posting

Answer (score 0):

Below a possible solution:

```
   x<-data.frame(color=c('pink','blue','yellow','pink'),number=c(3,2,9,7),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    print(x)
    #If you want to write the type from your R console
    input <- readline('input an element: ') 
    #If you want to try the code in a easy way
    input<-'blue'
    n=nrow(x)
    for(i in 1:n){
      if(x[i,1] %in% input) {
          print(x[i,])
      } 
    }
```

In this case I wrote `blue` in my `Console` and the output is:

```
  color number
2  blue      2
```

Pink in this case.

```
  color number
1  pink      3
  color number
4  pink      7
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I cannot get an output to your code.

Comment: The code works. 
I will update the answer by deleting the function readline. Do you have an error?

Comment: For some reason, it does not print out the rows and the output is just blank when I add readline function, but it works if I manually put the input, for example, input=blue.

Comment: Maybe the problem is: when you type the string (blue) in the console you have to write blue without the quotation marks (blue)

Answer (score 0):

**YOU DON'T NEED A LOOP** R vectorised operations are designed to handle stuff like this. Use `x$color %in% input` which will return a logical vector that has true for any row whose color is in the `input`, and then subset the data.frame with it:

```r
x=data.frame(color=c('pink','blue','yellow','pink'),number=c(3,2,9,7),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

input=readline('input an element: ')

print(x[x$color %in% input,])
```